# Design sidebar with border

Tags: html, css, psd

I have a design in PSD file like that: original design psd

[image]

and now, I'm trying convert this design on psd file to html file. This is my result and it isn't look like design: convert to html

[image]

Comment: Please Put Your HTML and CSS to know what you do?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Please put your code(what have you tried?) and elaborate your problem, so we may understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: inspect your element using F12 you can get idea.

Comment: OK I'm fine. I have resolved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make the li and a elements 100% width, display block. give the  a padding of 30px left or so, and then give it a left border of 3px solid transparent. On hover, change the border color to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to say without seeing the code, but most likely you should use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left` on those list elements to create the distance from the left border of the parent element.